# Incorrect Reflection of Glossy Over Glossy

Tags: materials, node-editor

Here's the Render:
[image]

I hope you may see the wrong reflection of jug on that glass. Jug colors are fully swapped there.
I think I have some incorrect node setup.
[image]

Comment: Any chance you could post the blend file? You can do that here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then add the link to your question. It will make it much easier to diagnose that way.

Comment: Also does it look similar if you just use a glass shader? If so then it's just how the reflections work. If not, then it's a material issue for sure and we can go from there.

Comment: @Brenticus ok. let me try only glass shader first as you said

Comment: @Brenticus that didn't work the issue same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you actually don't have a problem, it just looks like you do.

In 3d worlds, that is quite common to see, because they are so perfect that we don't see the little variations or issues that happen in real life that make things look right. Also, when you have any curved surfaces, things can get flipped around or upside down very easily.

It looks to me like the reflection of the jug is just flipped upside down. It's a bit hard to see in the image you posted, but it looks like it's reflecting off some curved glass objects, and you'll have refraction too, so there are plenty of ways that the light can bounce and bend, which gives the results you see.

It's like looking into the concave side of a spoon, or a reflection of a shiny pot that curves inward. Things just start to look a little weird when you have reflections and refraction with curved surfaces. Combine that with how 3d worlds look too perfect and you're bound to see cases where things don't look quite right, even though they physically are.

Comment: According to you that's not an issue?

Comment: Well it's behaving exactly how it should. It might not be what you want, but given the setup you have, it's doing what it's supposed to. If you want to change it you can do that, but there's nothing wrong with your material that would cause any incorrect reflections.